# Как разбить строку без пробелов по регистру?

Tags: python, строки, split

Есть строковые переменные вида:

```
siRNA, shRNA, sgRNA, miR-123, mutGene, lentivirusGENE, pDNA-ABC
```

Как разбить строку на две части по типу "приставка", "Корень". Приставка состоит из символов только в нижнем регистре, "Корень" всегда начинается с заглавной буквы, но может состоят из цифр, символов разного регистра и тп.

Как бы максимально просто это реализовать?

На выходе должен быть список вида:

```
['si', 'RNA'], ['mut', 'Gene'], ['p', 'DNA-ABC']
```

Спасибо))

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 7):

Воспользуйтесь регулярными выражениями:

```
import re

def parse_str(s):
    res = re.findall(r"([a-z]+)([A-Z]+.*)", s)
    if not res:
        return None
    return res[0]
```

тесты

```
In [229]: parse_str("siRNA")
Out[229]: ('si', 'RNA')

In [230]: parse_str("mutGene")
Out[230]: ('mut', 'Gene')

In [231]: parse_str("miR-123")
Out[231]: ('mi', 'R-123')

In [232]: parse_str("blah-blah-blah")
```